# How can I install phpmyadmin on OpsWorks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks

I am trying to install phpmyadmin on opsworks using a custom cookbook. I am very new to chef and so I really don't know what I am doing.

I'm using this cookbook: https://github.com/priestjim/chef-phpmyadmin

And specified my Stack to use that custom cookbook. But I don't see in the logs that phpmyadmin is installed or running.

The instance setup fails with this error message:

================================================================================

Recipe Compile Error
Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound

could not find recipe default for cookbook php

[2014-06-06T10:48:16+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers [2014-06-06T10:48:16+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete [2014-06-06T10:48:16+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out [2014-06-06T10:48:16+00:00] ERROR: could not find recipe default for cookbook php [2014-06-06T10:48:16+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

A little guidance please?

Thanks!

Comment: Best option is to not do it at all - phpMyAdmin has a history of security vulnerabilities and is a commonly attacked system. http://www.adminer.org/ is a better option, but even better is no web-based SQL management at all - use a client like MySQL Workbench, Sequel Pro, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to cookbook dependencies. Every cookbook can depend on others, and these dependencies are listed in metadata.rb (or metadata.json).

In your case:

```
depends           'php'
```

The phpmyadmin cookbook requires the php cookbook to be present, as stated in the Requirements section on the GitHub page. So you will need to get that cookbook and make it available in OpsWorks.

Also, please note that you will need to install a web server as well (such as apache or nginx) and configure it to serve PMA.